# Apache proxypass not working

Tags: apache-2.2, proxypass

Im trying to redirect http://domain.com/fw to my firewall, which is 192.168.x.x.

When using proxypass, i get this errors in my log, and a 404 in my client:

```
[error] [client x.x.x.x] File does not exist: /var/www/fw
```

This is my vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Servername domain.com
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /fw http://192.168.x.x
ProxyPassReverse /fw http://192.168.x.x
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas?

(Apache/2.2.22 (Debian))

apachectl -S

```
 wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www:4)
         port 80 namevhost www.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www:4)
         port 80 namevhost domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www:10)
         port 80 namevhost domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www:16)
         port 80 namevhost domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www:24)
         port 80 namevhost domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www:30)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: can you please add the output of `apachectl -S`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the config is obviously wrong based on what little information is given, but the user is no longer around to give the information necessary to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

normally ProxyPass should have an URL part lile `/` in this case.

Can you try the following?

```
ProxyPass /fw http://192.168.x.x/
ProxyPassReverse /fw http://192.168.x.x/
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a silly question but is the module enabled?  I don't believe it's enabled by default, nor installed for that matter.

Comment: LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so